# DBMS_ALERT.WAITANY uses up to 100% cpu

Tags: performance, oracle

We have an application that uses `DBMS_ALERT.WAITANY`. Because  the users complained that the application becomes so slow at certain intervals we looked at the enterprise manager of our Oracle 11 DB. We saw that in the same intervals `DBMS_ALERT.WAITANY` uses up to 100% of one cpu.

Is there a way to know what  notification causes `DBMS_ALERT.WAITANY` to use so much resource ?

Thanks
Andreas

Comment: Are you calling `waitany` in a loop, and are you setting a `timeout`? I've seen a problem before where the timeout effectively became zero and the loop was spinning; `dbms_alert` wasn't the problem, it was the calling looping that was spinning and causing the load. Just a thought.

Comment: What OS is running on your server?

Comment: No timeout passed so this is not the problem. @Alex Poole

Comment: Or DB runs on SLES 11 @BobJarvis

Comment: Not sure, but maybe "busy waiting" problem? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting